# how to create hotkey for doubleclick?

Tags: windows-7, hotkeys

When working I often need to select an entire word by put the cursor on that word (`variable` for e.g.) and it can be mabe via doubleckick.

But I'm interested how can I make a hotkey for this (not to use mouse at all)?

I'm on `Windows 7` and using `Aptana` as IDE.

Does anyone know how to achieve this by configuring Windows or Aptana?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) - it can automate many tasks

example: the line `#a:: send {click 30}` will cause the mouse to click 30 times when I press Win+A

Comment: Just change the `{click 30}` to `{click 2}` and you will able to use it as double click.